# create a 3d playing surface/game board in opengl- c++

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d

I am trying to create a 3D box, that would play the role of a playing board/surface/room for a 3D game in C++, using OpenGl. As a starting point I found some code that does that for a 2D surface. My question would be how to modify the following code to serve my purpose:

```
for (float  i = -width; i + 0.1 <= width; i += 0.1) {
    for (float j = -height; j + 0.1 <= height; j+= 0.1) {
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
        glVertex3f(i, 0, j);
        glVertex3f(i, 0, j + 0.1);
        glVertex3f(i + 0.1, 0, j + 0.1);
        glVertex3f(i + 0.1, 0, j);

        glEnd();
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what exactly is *your purpose*?

Comment: @Constantinius I am trying to create a 3D game, where a player must dodge incoming 3D asteroids. With this question I am trying to clarify how to create the room/box/setting where the player and the asteroids can move around

Comment: You mean your background plane? You should specify what exactly you are trying to do. For a "board" a simple plane consisting of 2 triangles would suffice. A "room" would require 4 walls and 1 back plane. I'm sorry, but I cannot spot a specific problem/question there.

Comment: so the player will be inside of the cube and cube will be texturized with some space bitmaps?

Comment: the player will be inside the cube, but the cube doesn't have to be visible, it should have more of the role of setting the boundries

Comment: if it doesnt have to be visible, then you dont need cube:) if boundaries are for collision detection then you can do it with planes, no need for cube geometry

Comment: ok..can you point me towards an example? can I still make use of the code above?

Comment: sorry I can only give you some hints, you can use some cube drawing code (like in the link in my answer), to draw asteroids then you need to experiment with camera position, rotation and translation of each asteroids and then you need code to calculate collision with whatever weapon should destroy those asteroids. That is quite some code, but it is great fun to write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use above code 6 times but each time apply different rotation/translation matrix, or you can do it the right way and generate correct geometry for missing 5 walls of your box. There are lots of samples for drawing cubes, ie.:

http://www.opengl.org/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/examples.html